# X and y coordinates while mousedown

Tags: javascript, canvas, mousemove, mousedown

I am currently making a game that requires the player to drag around an object on a touch screen device.

I've used the event listener `mousemove`, and it has worked on my Intel XDK emulator, but now that I move it to a touch screen device, I need an touch event that is `mousemove` and `mousedown`, and I am not sure how to do that.

Example of ideal code:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove" && "mousedown", function(e){  
    pointerX = e.pageX;
    pointerY = e.pageY;
}
```

So this ideal code spits out x and y when the mouse is down, and it has moved.

If anyone knows the legit syntax or a different method of doing this, it would be a great help.

I don't want to incorporate JQuery into this, just pure JS.

Thanks! :)

**Edit: Let me rephrase this so it is all straight forward. While the user is dragging an object I need a function that spits out x and y of the pointer the entire drag.**

Comment: "I need an event listener that is mousemove and mousedown, and I am not sure how to do that."  I am assuming you mean touch events?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Yes that's what I meant, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per MDN:

> The EventTarget.addEventListener() method registers the specified listener on the EventTarget it's called on. The event target may be an Element in a document, the Document itself, a Window, or any other object that supports events (such as XMLHttpRequest).

Note the "eventTarget" above. The AddEventListener method takes only one string which represents EventType. You'll need to write a custom function in order to iterate multiple events:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("myDiv");

['mousedown', 'mousemove'].forEach(eventType => {
  target.addEventListener(eventType, (event) => {
    target.innerText = `x: ${event.pageX} y: ${event.pageY}`;
  });
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you.

Comment: Ouch that hurts my brain.....
`{  
       const target = document.getElementById("myDiv");    
       ['mousedown','mousemove'].forEach((eventType) => {
           target.addEventListener(eventType, (event) => {
               target.textContent = `  `x: ${event.pageX} y: ${event.pageY}` `;
           });
       });
    }
`

Comment: thanks for your time reviewing my answer and my apologies that I hurt your brain. I hope you can still make good use of it ;)

Comment: :) though the use of innerText will trigger a reflow for each mouse event that can be avoided if you use textContent, brain no hurt no more..

Answer (score 1):

For touch devices, you should be looking into `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchcancel` and `touchmove`.

> Touch events are similar to mouse events except they support simultaneous touches and at different locations on the touch surface.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events`

Comment: I read it, and I still don't understand how I am supposed to execute a function while the mouse is down and moving. Sorry if these are easier questions, I'm pretty new to touch events.

Answer (score 1):

**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)** has a great post on touch events. The posts are not just full of quality information but also there are lots of javascript code shown which will provide you with a good resource for touch events.

### Interfaces

[**TouchEvent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent)

Represents an event that occurs when the state of touches on the surface changes.

[**Touch**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch)

Represents a single point of contact between the user and the touch surface.

[**TouchList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchList)

Represents a group of touches; this is used when the user has, for example, multiple fingers on the surface at the same time.

---

### *How does this solve my current problem?*

The information above provides greater detail for all the types of events you may want to look into. However, for your specific problem, you should look into [**touchmove**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove) & **[touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend)** events.

**Side note** -  check [**touchmove**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove) & **[touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend)** links for compatibility concerns.

Comment: So how would I use this to run simultaneous touches? I am just asking for the x and y when the player is dragging this object.

Comment: Oh... I tried it on a mobile device and it didn't work. I'm using Intel XDK build and it works on the emulator but not on the phone...

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi interesting that it works on your emulator but not the phone. Well, that's another problem now, but I will loop into it.

Comment: It just freezes, the object won't move. I feel like it's because a computer perceives a drag as a drag, and a phone sees it as a tap that is not done yet.